# creating and positioning venn-diagram with css

Tags: css, venn-diagram

I am trying to create an effect with css -- I want three overlapping circles looking like a venn-diagram.  I want to apply css-animation transforms on the circles so they appear to pulsate.

I am currently trying to use `&#183;` or · as a venn diagram circle.  However, as you can (hopefully) see, the position of this character is not flush left or right... and therefore positioning of it is terribly difficult.  Note how in the picture below the dots are outside of a bounding box of 100px x 100px.

[image]

I want to position the venn-diagram's circles into their parent element so it is easy to position the venn-diagram element elsewhere.  Is there an altogether better approach to how to create this look?  Custom font?  SVG?

```
<style>

@-webkit-keyframes dot1
{
    0%   {color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);}
    50%  {color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .8);}
    100%  {color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);}
}


.dot
{
    font-size: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}

.dot1
{
    -webkit-animation:dot1 2s infinite;
    top: 0;
}  

.dot2
{
    -webkit-animation:dot1 2s infinite;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0;
}  

.dot3
{
    -webkit-animation:dot1 2s infinite;
    top: 10px;
    left: 15px;
}  

.container
{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: pink;
    border-width: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class='container'>
  <span class='dot dot1'>&#183;</span>
  <span class='dot dot2'>&#183;</span>
  <span class='dot dot3'>&#183;</span>
  </div>

</body>
```

http://jsbin.com/ozeham/1/edit

Comment: Different browsers may render text in different ways. Using an image is probably the most pixel-accurate method. However, try playing with the `line-height` property of `.dot`. http://jsbin.com/oparic/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using the dot-character you can simply create a circle using ccs3 (`border-radius`). those circles are a lot easier to control: http://jsbin.com/ozeham/3/

Answer (score 0):

SVG would work fine - but if you want to stick with CSS try using a smaller container for only the venn diagram and then positioning the container to move the entire diagram together.

E.g.

```
<div class="venn">
    <div class="dot dot1"></div>
    <div class="dot dot2"></div>
    <div class="dot dot3"></div>
</div>
```

Then use `position: absolute` for the dots (and `top` and `left` properties to tweak position). For the container, use `position: absolute` *or* `position: relative` to position it inside the box:

```
.venn {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.dot {
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ozeham/6/edit

Answer (score 0):

Number of ways you could approach this. I'm not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve by this. I would use border-radius to create the circles.

http://jsbin.com/ozeham/10/edit

Answer (score 0):

Why bother using characters as circles, when you can use syntax like this:

```
.circle {
    width:whatever;
    height:whatever;
    border-radius:50%;
    opacity:33%;
}

#foo {
    background-color:#FF0000;
}


#bar {
    background-color:#00FF00;
}


#qux {
    background-color:#0000FF;
}

.container {
    position:relative;
    right:whatever;
    top:whatever;
}
```

Along with the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle" id="foo"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="bar"></div>
    <div class="circle" id="qux"></div>
</div>
```